# 802.11n router and 802.11g network card

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, 802.11n, 802.11g

I have a D-link DIR-524 802.11n router. My PC is having 802.11a/b/g. The issues is that I'm unable to connect to the router when 802.11n is turned on. As soon as I disable 802.11n feature. I can connect to the router!!

Is there any was I can connect with my PC with 802.11n turned on??

EDIT: A picture of the web interface of router..
[image]

Comment: What model is the router - doesn't it have a mixed (g and n) mode?

Comment: it only gives me 2 option for 802.11n namely, 1. Auto and 2. Off..I will post the configuration page later....

Comment: Check with the manufacturer of your router to see if there is a firmware update for your device, it key be that an update could add a dual mode functionality.

Comment: i called the customer care of D-link, but they are more lame than I am.. :P. Says the router by default supports g/n dual mode. If that's the case, then why am I not able to connect!!!

Comment: Can you post a picture of the Advanced tab? I am looking for an option that my effect connectivity but I cannot find it on this page.

Answer (score 0):

One difference might be the 5 GHz mode which is exclusive to n and a modes. For n, this is optional, but you can force it on your router or your network interface.

Ive checked the [data sheet](ftp://ftp10.dlink.com/pdfs/products/DI-524/DI-524_ds.pdf), there is no 5GHz mode. And your computer's network can only do 2.4GHz, so that should match.

I see no reason why you should turn the n mode on, it won't bring anything special in your case.

Comment: didn't I mention my network card is 802.11 a/b/g.

Comment: I live with my roommates and all of them have a n network card, which essentially make me force its use, since they will have higher data rates...